# Creating a sentence with the verb "tell"

Tags: sentence-structure

> I'd like to **tell** you that I'll go to Ngwe Saung beach this year after the exam.

Is the sentence grammatically correct? Thanks.

Comment: The fact that by saying so states the obvious action of 'telling'. Better use the verb '**inform**'. But there's **no** problem in your sentence. This comment is a mere opinion. Also, please include the point of confusion when you post questions. This question may likely be considered as a question soliciting proofreading (which is not quite tolerated here)

Comment: The sentence looks fine to me. I'd like to tell you that the verb **inform** would be a bit too formal for the purpose, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

This sentence is not incorrect, but it sounds strange to a native speaker.

Consider the phrase "I'd like to" - it is a future tense discussion of something that you want.  Because you have not yet gotten what you want, it implies there is an obstacle preventing you from getting what you want.  For instance, "I'd like to climb that mountain someday" [implied: but I will need to get in shape first.]

In common usage, the obstacle is permission from the person listening.  For instance, getting into a taxi and telling the driver "I'd like to go to the airport" [implied: if you are willing to take me there.]  This offers the listener the opportunity to object or agree with the plan, and is considered more polite than simply assuming agreement, as in "Take me to the airport."

In this case, you are saying you would like to tell me something.  However, since you can immediately tell me the information, there did not seem to be any obstacle to overcome.  Since you proceeded to the conclusion without a pause or break, it feels like I was asked permission but not allowed an opportunity to object.

One way to make this sentence feel more natural is to omit the first few words.  You spend some time introducing the idea in an overly formal way, but your message is simply "I'll go to Ngwe Saung beach this year after the exam."

Conversely, if you make the message more formal, you justify the introduction.  "I'd like to tell you something.  After the exams, I will be leaving for Ngwe Saung beach."

If you just want a natural and common use of the word "tell", use it as a request of someone else.  For instance, "Tell me about your trip to Ngwe Saung beach."  "Tell" works well as an instruction, such as "Tell her about your exams."

Answer (score 0):

The stated sentence is correct for usage in our own daily English.

You can see a lot of examples of the same kind of sentence formation like bellow:

> 1. I would like to inform you that I will be on leave..........
> 2. i would like to inform you that i will be taking a working vacation...
> 3. i would like to inform you that tomorrow we will be killed with our families..

etc.